# Unable to establish Kafka source connection with azure IoT hub

Tags: azure, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have been trying to resolve this issue from past 5 days till today. I have azure Iot Hub up and running and many devices are able to connect and send messages to it.
Meanwhile I was exploring options to lay pipeline with kafka source connection and came across [toketi-kafka-connect-iothub](https://github.com/Azure/toketi-kafka-connect-iothub) and used it to integrated with my iot hub. Now, messages sent from devices to IOT hub are able to recieve on the other end of kafka reciever via connector but not when I try to send some data through curl script to IoT hub.

I have verfied that azure IoT hub is able to receive messages from my curl script. And if I produce some messages on kafka topic manually, message is able to receive on the other end. This
confirm the issue is with connector. It will be very helpful you anyone can help me to narrow down root cause.

```
   curl -X POST \
  'https://XXX.azure-devices.net/devices/devvXXX/messages/events?api-version=2016-02-03' \
  -H 'authorization: SharedAccessSignature sr=device_key_valid' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'content-type: application/json' \
  -d '{ "name":"John", "age":31, "city":"New York" }'
```

And my kafka server setting looks something like below:

```
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
# contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
# this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
# The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
# (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
# the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

# see kafka.server.KafkaConfig for additional details and defaults

############################# Server Basics #############################

# The id of the broker. This must be set to a unique integer for each broker.
broker.id=0
 message.max.bytes=1347385956
############################# Socket Server Settings #############################

# The address the socket server listens on. It will get the value returned from 
# java.net.InetAddress.getCanonicalHostName() if not configured.
#   FORMAT:
#     listeners = listener_name://host_name:port
#   EXAMPLE:
#     listeners = PLAINTEXT://your.host.name:9092
#listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092

# Hostname and port the broker will advertise to producers and consumers. If not set, 
# it uses the value for "listeners" if configured.  Otherwise, it will use the value
# returned from java.net.InetAddress.getCanonicalHostName().
#advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://your.host.name:9092

# Maps listener names to security protocols, the default is for them to be the same. See the config documentation for more details
#listener.security.protocol.map=PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,SSL:SSL,SASL_PLAINTEXT:SASL_PLAINTEXT,SASL_SSL:SASL_SSL

# The number of threads that the server uses for receiving requests from the network and sending responses to the network
num.network.threads=3

# The number of threads that the server uses for processing requests, which may include disk I/O
num.io.threads=8

# The send buffer (SO_SNDBUF) used by the socket server
socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400

# The receive buffer (SO_RCVBUF) used by the socket server
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400

# The maximum size of a request that the socket server will accept (protection against OOM)
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600


############################# Log Basics #############################

# A comma separated list of directories under which to store log files
log.dirs=/tmp/kafka-logs

# The default number of log partitions per topic. More partitions allow greater
# parallelism for consumption, but this will also result in more files across
# the brokers.
num.partitions=1

# The number of threads per data directory to be used for log recovery at startup and flushing at shutdown.
# This value is recommended to be increased for installations with data dirs located in RAID array.
num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1

############################# Internal Topic Settings  #############################
# The replication factor for the group metadata internal topics "__consumer_offsets" and "__transaction_state"
# For anything other than development testing, a value greater than 1 is recommended for to ensure availability such as 3.
offsets.topic.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.min.isr=1

############################# Log Flush Policy #############################

# Messages are immediately written to the filesystem but by default we only fsync() to sync
# the OS cache lazily. The following configurations control the flush of data to disk.
# There are a few important trade-offs here:
#    1. Durability: Unflushed data may be lost if you are not using replication.
#    2. Latency: Very large flush intervals may lead to latency spikes when the flush does occur as there will be a lot of data to flush.
#    3. Throughput: The flush is generally the most expensive operation, and a small flush interval may lead to excessive seeks.
# The settings below allow one to configure the flush policy to flush data after a period of time or
# every N messages (or both). This can be done globally and overridden on a per-topic basis.

# The number of messages to accept before forcing a flush of data to disk
log.flush.interval.messages=100

# The maximum amount of time a message can sit in a log before we force a flush
#log.flush.interval.ms=1000

############################# Log Retention Policy #############################

# The following configurations control the disposal of log segments. The policy can
# be set to delete segments after a period of time, or after a given size has accumulated.
# A segment will be deleted whenever *either* of these criteria are met. Deletion always happens
# from the end of the log.

# The minimum age of a log file to be eligible for deletion due to age
log.retention.hours=168

# A size-based retention policy for logs. Segments are pruned from the log unless the remaining
# segments drop below log.retention.bytes. Functions independently of log.retention.hours.
#log.retention.bytes=1073741824

# The maximum size of a log segment file. When this size is reached a new log segment will be created.
log.segment.bytes=1073741824

# The interval at which log segments are checked to see if they can be deleted according
# to the retention policies
log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000

############################# Zookeeper #############################

# Zookeeper connection string (see zookeeper docs for details).
# This is a comma separated host:port pairs, each corresponding to a zk
# server. e.g. "127.0.0.1:3000,127.0.0.1:3001,127.0.0.1:3002".
# You can also append an optional chroot string to the urls to specify the
# root directory for all kafka znodes.
zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181

# Timeout in ms for connecting to zookeeper
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=6000


############################# Group Coordinator Settings #############################

# The following configuration specifies the time, in milliseconds, that the GroupCoordinator will delay the initial consumer rebalance.
# The rebalance will be further delayed by the value of group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms as new members join the group, up to a maximum of max.poll.interval.ms.
# The default value for this is 3 seconds.
# We override this to 0 here as it makes for a better out-of-the-box experience for development and testing.
# However, in production environments the default value of 3 seconds is more suitable as this will help to avoid unnecessary, and potentially expensive, rebalances during application startup.
group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms=300
```

And connector settings are like below:

```
############################# Connector Config #############################
# Identifies the Azure IoT Hub source connector.
# Do not change this if you want to use the Azure IotHub source connector
connector.class=com.microsoft.azure.iot.kafka.connect.source.IotHubSourceConnector

# Name of the connector
name=AzureIotHubConnector

# Maximum number of tasks that should be created for this connector.
# More tasks means more parallelism. For optimal performance,
# this should equal the number of Azure IoT Hub partitions
tasks.max=1

# Kafka topic to which the data should be written to
Kafka.Topic=test

############################# IoTHub Config #############################
# Azure IoT Hub settings can be retrieved from the Azure portal at
# https://portal.azure.com. For more information on how to get the IoT Hub settings,
# please refer to the documentation here -
# https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-create-through-portal#endpoints
# https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-java-java-getstarted

# "IoT Hub" >> your hub >> "Endpoints" >> "Events" >> "Event Hub-compatible name"
IotHub.EventHubCompatibleName=iothub-valisnameXX

# "IoT Hub" >> your hub > "Endpoints" >> "Events" >> "Event Hub-compatible endpoint"
IotHub.EventHubCompatibleEndpoint=sb://XXvalidoneXX.servicebus.windows.net/
# "IoT Hub" >> your hub >> "Shared access policies"
# You can use the predefined value "service"
IotHub.AccessKeyName=iothubowner

# "IoT Hub" >> your hub >> "Shared access policies" >> key name >> "Primary key"
IotHub.AccessKeyValue=xxxvalidvaluexxx

# "IoT Hub" >> your hub > "Endpoints" >> "Events" >> Consumer groups
# "$Default" is predefined value.
IotHub.ConsumerGroup=XXvalidgrupnaeXX

# "IoT Hub" >> your hub >> "Endpoints" >> "Events" >> "Partitions"
IotHub.Partitions=2

# The time from which to start retrieving messages from IoTHub.
# The value should be in UTC and in the format yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ssZ
# This setting is mutually exclusive with IotHub.Offsets.
# If StartTime is provided, the Offsets value will be ignored.
IotHub.StartTime=2018-07-18 06:02:53,534
# The offsets for each IoTHub partition from which to start retrieving messages
# from IoTHub, as a comma separated string. For example, for 4 partitions,
# the value would be something like "abc,lmn,pqr,xyz".
# This setting is mutually exclusive with IotHub.StartTime.
# If StartTime is provided, the Offsets value will be ignored.
IotHub.Offsets=4

# The size of each batch for retrieving messages from IoTHub. The max supported value is 999.
BatchSize=1

# The max duration in seconds to wait for a full batch when retrieving messages from IoTHub. The default is 60.
ReceiveTimeout=60
```

I am not able to differentiate how my curl request is different from the request coming directly from my device... Not sure if there is anything linked with SSL.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, wrong obeservation. Packets sent from curl script where actually being received on the other end of kafka, but where in queue. I just realized now, when I saw yesterday's packets being read today.